# `match.call()` and `sys.call()` called from a function of the enclosing environment

Tags: r, function, environment, rlang, tidyeval

`match.call()` and `sys.call()` are straightforward to get the call to the current executed function, however I cannot seem to get the call to the function one level up reliably.

I would like to build the following function factory

```
factory <- function(){

  CALL <- function(){
    # does operations on what would be the output of match.call() and sys.call() 
    # if they were executed in the manufactured function
  }

  CALL2 <- function() {
    # calls CALL() and does other operations
  }

  function(x, y){
    # calls CALL() and CALL2(), not necessarily at the top level
  }
}
```

Here is a simplified example, with expected output, where I just try to print the correct `match.call()` and `sys.call()` :

**code**

I expect your answer to edit the following by adding code where `# INSERT SOME CODE` comments are found.

My code at the end calls the `CALL` and `CALL2` functions in different ways, to test test the robustnes of the solution.

Each of these ways is expected to print the same output, which is what `{print(match.call()); print(sys.call())}` would print.

```
factory <- function(){
  CALL <- function(){
    # INSERT SOME CODE HERE
  }
  CALL2 <- function() {
    # INSERT SOME CODE HERE IF NECESSARY
    CALL()
  }

  function(x, y){
    # INSERT SOME CODE HERE IF NECESSARY

    # Don't edit following code
    message("call from top level")
    CALL()
    message("call from lst")
    dplyr::lst(CALL())
    message("call from lapply")
    lapply(CALL(), identity)
    message("call from sub function")
    f <- function() CALL()
    f()
    message("call from another function from enclosing env")
    CALL2()
    message("call from lst")
    dplyr::lst(CALL2())
    message("call from lapply")
    lapply(CALL2(), identity)
    message("call from sub function")
    g <- function() CALL2()
    g()
    invisible(NULL)
  }
}
```

**input**

To test the function the following code should be executed :

```
fun <- factory()
fun("foo", y = "bar")
```

OR

```
fun2 <- function(){
  fun("foo", y = "bar")
}
fun2()
```

This way the solution is tested with 2 different call stacks, again for robustness.

**desired output**

Anytime `CALL` is called in the example above, should print the following, however it is called :

```
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
```

Which means the complete output when running `fun("foo", y = "bar")` or `fun2()` should be :

```
call from top level
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from lst
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from lapply
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from sub function
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from another function from enclosing env
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from lst
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from lapply
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
call from sub function
fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
fun("foo", y = "bar")
```

Maybe `rlang` / `tidyeval` can come to the rescue ?

---

**WHAT I TRIED**

I believe I found a way to succeed with `match.call()`.

To make sure `match.call()` is executed in the right environment, I create a binding `ENV` to the environment of my manufactured function with `ENV <- environment()`. Then I can retrieve this environment by calling `ENV <- eval.parent(quote(ENV))` in `CALL()` and `CALL2()`, and then can get the proper output by calling `eval(quote(match.call()), ENV)`.

This same strategy doesn't work with `sys.call()` however.

```r
factory <- function(){

  CALL <- function(){
    ENV <- eval.parent(quote(ENV))
    print(eval(quote(match.call()), ENV))
    print(eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV))
  }

  CALL2 <- function() {
    ENV <- eval.parent(quote(ENV))
    CALL()
  }

  function(x, y){
    ENV <- environment()
    message("call from top level")
    CALL()
    message("call from lst")
    dplyr::lst(CALL())
    message("call from lapply")
    lapply(CALL(), identity)
    message("call from sub function")
    f <- function() CALL()
    f()
    message("call from another function from enclosing env")
    CALL2()
    message("call from lst")
    dplyr::lst(CALL2())
    message("call from lapply")
    lapply(CALL2(), identity)
    message("call from sub function")
    g <- function() CALL2()
    g()
    invisible(NULL)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
fun <- factory()
fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from top level
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from another function from enclosing env
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
```

```
fun2 <- function(){
  fun("foo", y = "bar")
}
fun2()
#> call from top level
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from another function from enclosing env
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As you can see the output shows `eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV)` where I want to see `fun("foo", y = "bar")`.

Instead of `print(eval(quote(sys.call()), ENV))` I also tried `print(sys.call(1))` and `print(sys.call(sys.parent()))` and both sometimes print the right thing, but are not robust.

Comment: (Is this an example of a "Mwe", where the "M" is intentionally capitalized and akin to the `M`ega/`m`icro abbreviations? Wow, Moody, this ain't short ...)

Comment: I tried hard to strip it to the minimum :).  And I drew a line to separate the question from what I try, couldn't get better sorry :D

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but the R `trace` function is often used to trace calls.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper That's fine ... you know as well as I do that a multi-page question doesn't hold attention well ... I'm sorry I don't have the time today to really dive into it. Good luck!

Comment: the question might be reformulated roughly as : how do I fix `factory_sc1` so `CALL` ALWAYS prints `fun_sc1("foo", y = "bar")` wether I call directly `fun_sc1`, or via another function. I don't know how I would use `trace` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a different point of view of the problem itself,
you could just save the call in the enclosing environment,
always matching it in the "main" function:

```
factory <- function(){
  matched_call <- NULL

  CALL <- function(){
    print(matched_call)
  }
  CALL2 <- function() {
    CALL()
  }

  function(x, y){
    matched_call <<- match.call()
    on.exit(matched_call <<- NULL)

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That's neat, I will probably use this in my code finally, I like how it leaves the manufactured function's environment clean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's robust or idiomatic but I could solve it by using `sys.call()` on `rlang::frame_position()`.

The problem is that `frame_position()` is soft-deprecated without proper replacement, so I defined a function `frame_pos()` which seems work the same in my use case :

```
frame_pos <- function(frame) {
  pos <- which(sapply(sys.frames(), identical, frame))
  if(!length(pos)) pos <- 0
  pos
}
```

```
factory <- function(){
  CALL <- function(){
    ENV <- eval.parent(quote(ENV))
    print(eval(quote(match.call()), ENV))
    print(sys.call(rlang::frame_position(ENV)))
    print(sys.call(frame_pos(ENV)))
  }
  CALL2 <- function() {
    ENV <- eval.parent(quote(ENV))
    CALL()
  }
  function(x, y){
    ENV <- environment()
    message("call from top level")
    CALL()
    message("call from lst")
    dplyr::lst(CALL())
    message("call from lapply")
    lapply(CALL(), identity)
    message("call from sub function")
    f <- function() CALL()
    f()
    message("call from another function from enclosing env")
    CALL2()
    message("call from lst")
    dplyr::lst(CALL2())
    message("call from lapply")
    lapply(CALL2(), identity)
    message("call from sub function")
    g <- function() CALL2()
    g()
    invisible(NULL)
  }
}
```

```
fun <- factory()
fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from top level
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from another function from enclosing env
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
```

```
fun2 <- function() fun("foo", y = "bar")
fun2()
#> call from top level
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from another function from enclosing env
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lst
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from lapply
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> call from sub function
#> fun(x = "foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
#> fun("foo", y = "bar")
```